# merge_when_pipeline_succeeds is always set to false via API call

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I modified Merge Requests paramter "Merge checks" in GitLab UI, to enable Pipelines must succeed in a project settings.

When creating a merge request manually in the UI I see the merge blocked until the pipeline terminates and succeeds to be have the merge button enabled.

However, when using [Merge Requests API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html) the attribute merge_when_pipeline_succeeds is always set to false when calling a GET /projects/:id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid

merge_when_pipeline_succeds is false when creating the MR via GitLab UI or via GitLab API call.

Do you know why the value of merge_when_pipeline_succeeds is not the same as the one configured in UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` is separate from the check you enabled for your project. This property means that once the pipeline succeeds, the Merge Request will be automatically merged (true) or not (false). The check simply says that you *cannot* merge it until a pipeline succeeds, but doesn't affect the physical merging whatsoever.

You can see the result of all your configured merge checks in the `merge_status` property:

```json
"merge_when_pipeline_succeeds": true,
"merge_status": "can_be_merged",
```

These are copied from the response in the API docs you linked above.

`merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` is set to true, so this means that once the pipeline finishes, and as long as there wasn't a failure, the Merge Request will automatically be merged.

`merge_status` is set to `can_be_merged`, so this is saying that any configured merge checks have all passed.

Comment: Thanks for for answer and clear explanation. Do you know to set (maybe in the MR creation API call) `merge_when_pipeline_succeeds` to true ?

Comment: I imagine you'd be able to set this in the [Update Merge Request API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#update-mr) but have to admit I've only ever set it via the UI, so I'm not entirely sure.